# UIAction Sheet Not Dismissing When Pressing UIBarButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I am presenting a UIActionSheet from a UIBarButtonItem.  I want the action sheet to dismiss when I click the bar button again, instead it is creating a new one each time layered on top of each other.  Any ideas?

```
- (IBAction)actionButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Action Menu" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Help", @"Lock", nil];
    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [popupQuery showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
    [popupQuery release];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self erxButtonClicked];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        [self erxRefillButtonClicked];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would declare a `@property` for `popupQuery` on my class and use it to keep track of the action sheet.

```
- (IBAction)actionButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    // If self.popupQuery is not nil, it means the sheet is on screen and should be dismissed. The property is then set to nil so a new sheet can be created next time.
    if (self.popupQuery)
    {
        [self.popupQuery dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:self.popupQuery.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
        self.popupQuery = nil;

        return;
    }

    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Action Menu" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Help", @"Lock", nil];
    sheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    sheet.delegate = self;
    self.popupQuery = sheet;
    [sheet release];

    [self.popupQuery showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];  
}

// Implementing this method to be notified of when an action sheet dismisses by means other than tapping the UIBarButtonItem. We set the property to nil to prepare for lazy instantiation next time.
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    self.popupQuery = nil;
}
```

Comment: This works but now I have another problem.  If I press the button to show the popup, and i dismiss it by clicking anywhere on the screen, if I press the button again to display popover, i have to click it twice for it to show.  However, if I dismiss it initally by just clicking the button again, the next time I press it I only have to press it once as it works fine.

Comment: Updated my answer. The gist is to make yourself the delegate of the action sheet and implement `-actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` to be notified when the action sheet has been dismissed by means other than the bar button.

Comment: why not alloc the action sheet once, check if is it visible in the actionButtonClicked function, and if so dismiss it, else show it?